# Calculating Multiple Percents

Tags: math, probability

How would you calculate the chance that D will occur if A, B, and C does not?

For example, here is the chance that the defender will evade, parry, or block.

```
    A = 10% chance to evade, 90% chance to not evade
    B = 20% chance to parry, 80% chance to not parry
    C = 40% chance to block, 60% chance to not block
    D = P chance for direct hit
    P = probability that D will occur if A, B, and C do not occur.
```

If A does not occur, then B will occur etc.

**EDIT: So, for a full clear answer. The probability rolls go in this order: evade, parry, block.**

If defender evades, then defender will not parry, block, or be hit directly.

If defender parries, then defender will not block or be hit directly.

If defender blocks, then defender will not be hit directly.

If defender fails any of the above, then defender will be hit directly.

```
90% chance to not evade * 20% chance to parry = 18% chance to parry

100% - 18% chance to parry = 82% chance to not evade or parry

82% chance to not evade or parry * 40% chance to block = 32.8% chance to block

100% - 32.8% chance to block = 67.2% chance to be hit directly

    A = 10% chance to evade
    B = 18% chance to parry (from 20%)
    C = 32.8% chance to block (from 40%)
    D = 67.2% chance to be hit directly
```

Comment: Question is related to math, not to programming

Comment: Ops, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
10% (0.1) to evade => 90% (0.9) not evading
20% (0.2) to parry => 80% (0.8) not parrying
40% (0.4) to block => 60% (0.6) not blocking
```

for your example ("If A does not occur, then B will occur etc."):

10% (0.1) to evade => **90% of all attacks not evading and can be parrying or blocking**

20% (0.2) to parry from not evading attacks => (80% of not evading attacks can be parry) => 0nly 18% (0.9 not evading * 0.2) of all attacks can be parrying => **82% of all attacks not evading and not parrying and can be blocking**

40% (0.4) to block from not evading and not parrying attacks => (60% of not evading and not parrying attacks can be parry) => Only 32.8% (0.82 not evading and not parrying * 0.4) of all attacks can be blocked => **67.2% of all attacks not evading, not parrying and not blocking.**

**Defence = 32.8%**

for some sequence (such us, C -> B -> A ) of defence rotation can be another results.

Comment: Ohhh I think I got it now. So if I understand correctly, we first have the evade roll. Then we have 90% * the chance to parry to get 18%. And lastly you need to subtract your previous answer from 90% to get 82%. The real probability to get a successful parry roll will be 18%, but to continue with the block roll we need to use the 82% * .4 to get 32.8% chance to block. So now there is a 67.2% chance that you will be hit directly. Sorry about the defense thing I was a bit unclear on that, I meant it as a direct hit.

Comment: Yes, we have 67.2% chance to directly hit with your rotation: evade -> parry -> block

Comment: Alright, thanks so much! That question has literally been bothering me for a couple years lol. *In my previous comment I meant to put 100% instead of the second 90%*

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the evade parry and block chances are considered.

If the roll is just one with different outcomes, eg you roll a number in `[0,100)` and you have

```
0-9 evade
10-29 parry
30-69 block
70-99 nothing
```

then it is just `1 - (A+B+C) = 0.30 = 30%`.

If, instead, they are indipendent rolls then you must consider the chance of not passing each roll:

```
10% evade : 90% of not evading
20% parry : 80% of not parrying
40% block: 60% of not blocking
```

but they are 3 separate rolls so you have to multiply them, since you want to consider the probability of not passing any of three rolls:

```
(1-A)*(1-B)*(1-C) = 0.432 = 43.2%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
D = 1 - (A + B + C)
  = 1 - 70%
  = 30%
```